# Assigning Values to a Dictionary of Tables

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a situation in which Sales Managers reply to an automated email with lead times for primary and secondary leads. Their response would include a indication of which type of lead it was and the lead time. For example:

```
Primary_Lead 10
Secondary_Lead 20
```

I wrote a script to look through the emails (based on a certain subject) and find the lead times in the response. I want to add these to the Lead_Time dictionary of tables. I think everything works fine except for my last two lines which append values to `Sales Manager` and `Lead Time`. What am I doing wrong here? I know the whole email thing adds an additional level of complication that I don't need assistance with but wanted to provide actual code.

```
import win32com.client
import re

olFolderInbox = 6
olMailItem = 0

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')
inbox =  mapi.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
My_Folder = inbox.Folders("Leads")


Lead_Time = {
    'Primary_Leads':         {'Sales Manager' : [],'Lead Time' : []},
    'Secondary_Leads':       {'Sales Manager' : [],'Lead Time' : []}

}

for i in range (My_Folder.Items.Count): #loops through all emails in Leads Folder
  message = My_Folder.Items[i] #sets the message
  if "RE: Lead Time Report" in message.Subject: #checks for a certain subject
    for tbl in Lead_Time:
        if tbl.upper() in message.Body.upper():
          tbl['Sales Manager'].append map(int,re.findall(tbl +"* (\d+)",message.Body,re.I))
          tbl['Lead Time'].append message.sender
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `tbl['Sales Manager'].append(map(int,re.findall(tbl +"* (\d+)",message.Body,re.I)))` and `tbl['Lead Time'].append(message.sender)`?

Comment: @maccinza that yields an error: `string indices must be integers, not str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over the keys of `Lead_Time` when you really want to append to the values.

You can see this confusion in your own code:

```
for tbl in Lead_Time:
    if tbl.upper() in message.Body.upper():
        tbl['Sales Manager'].append
```

On the second line you treat `tbl` as the string that it is. On the third line you treat `tbl` like the array value associated with it in the dictionary.

You could change your code as follows:

```
Lead_Time[tbl]['Sales Manager'].append ...
Lead_Time[tbl]['Lead Time'].append ...
```

Or you could ask for both the key and the value when iterating:

```
for table_name, value in Lead_Time.items():
    if table_name.upper() in message.Body.upper():
        value['Sales Manager'].append ...
```

You can see the output of the default dict iterator with this much simpler example:

```
some_dict = {1: 2, 3: 4}
for key in some_dict:
    print key
```

This prints 1 and 3.